# Mac running macOS Mojave doesn't boot

Tags: mac, startup, mojave

I've updated to macOS Mojave weeks ago, and everything was working very well. However, yesterday my iMac (2014, I think?) didn't even boot, nor does it today.

The verbose mode shows this (I know I should post text, but I can't, for obvious reasons):

[image]

I found [only one](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8553546) question about the same error message on Apple forums, but it doesn't have any answers...

The boot drive check (from recovery mode and via `fsck` from Single user mode) didn't find any errors.

How can this be solved?

Comment: try running the `fsck` multiple times

Comment: you do have a disk error...`disk1s1: device is not readable`

Comment: it would be helpful if you wait till the Safe boot stops and show us the last lines.

Comment: @Buscar웃, just ran `fsck -fy` 2 times, and it shows "The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 appears to be OK". Furthermore, I'm writing this from Windows that's installed on the same HDD, so the drive should be OK.

Comment: please report the last lines when the Verbose mode stops ....

Comment: @Buscar웃, it doesn't seem to ever stop, unfortunately. It was sitting like that for like an hour yesterday, printing more and more of the `vm_map_delete` stuff... Right now I was able to mount the partition from Windows with APFS by Paragon. All the files appear to be fine.

Comment: great, did you say you fixed it ?

Comment: @Buscar웃, no, the disc is fine, the files are fine, but the mac still doesn't boot into macOS (however, it does boot into Windows)

Comment: sorry, but according to the Verbose mode the APFS partition is not fine, maybe you should use the restore.

Comment: You may also try reinstalling the OS preserving data

Comment: @Buscar웃, so, I made a backup on an external drive from Windows and started reinstallation from Recovery mode. It’s been running for hours, and seems to be stuck now. The progress bar is full, no messages are shown beneath it. Is this OK? I don’t feel like powering off the Mac because it may corrupt the hard drive.

Comment: sorry about that, it is trying to repair your disk, so let it work, if it does not succeed it will let you know

Answer (score 1):

I run `fsck -fy` three or four times, as suggested in the comments, but it didn't reveal any issues and kept telling me  "The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 appears to be OK".

I was lucky to have Windows installed alongside macOS with Bootcamp, so I booted into Windows to see whether the data on the macOS partition were fine. It turned out that one can't just view APFS drives in Windows, so I had to install a trial version of `APFS` by Paragon, which allows you to mount such drives from Windows.

The partition mounted successfully, and I was able to see all my data, so, apparently, nothing was lost or corrupted. I was even luckier to have a spare hard drive lying around and a device to connect it to a computer through USB, so I did that and copied the vast majority of my files from the (faulty?) macOS partition to this drive.

After the data were safe, I rebooted into Recovery mode, checked the partition from Disk Utility *once again*, which showed "...appears to be OK" again, and tried to reinstall the OS.

I know the installation process is supposed to be kinda long, but this one was *insanely* long. Everything seemed to have installed (no errors whatsoever), and it attempted to boot itself. It was doing that and showing me the usual apple logo on the white background and a full progress bar for literally **fifteen hours** because I was told to "let it work" and that it might repair the drive in the comments, and was hoping not to lose any data. Well, that went nowhere, so finally I just shut the Mac down. (BTW, after booting from Windows again I found out that all the data on the macOS partition were *still* intact)

I ended up wiping the macOS partition from the Disk Utility in the Recovery mode and installing macOS *once again*. This worked fine, and I got a fresh macOS Mojave installation, from which I'm writing this (semi-)answer. I can access all the data I copied to the external drive, nothing is corrupted.

---

TL;DR - did a backup (the partition was not corrupted), nuked the partition from orbit and did a clean installation; still no idea why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, i have 4 macs that all do this randomly. black screen or just the logo on boot. the only boot option that works is recovery (and that is on another partiation). On my iMac i can do an install (last time tried a complete new with migration) and first reboot after running a few hours back to the Apple.  I did try booting from a USB drive when it would not boot from the Apple internal SSD (imac) and that worked. I cam cloning the boot disk over to an external usb SSD drive to see how long that works. I don't know if this is an hardware thing (odd that 4 different macs have the issue) or a Mojave thing. I have sent in several feedbacks with no luck. if I can prove it works using USB reliably I guess I will drive the 40 mils to an apple store.

Comment: _Four_ macs?! That _has_ to be to do with Mojave, dude! Personally, I’ve never ever run into anything like that for years, with the same iMac. Now that you have _four_ acting up, Apple must’ve messed something up in macOS. The data seems to be fine, though, so it’s not that bad.